# How to allow user-defined functions in intel's auto-vectorization?

Tags: user-defined-functions, vectorization, intel, icc

Assuming I have the following piece of code:

```cpp
class Vec3
{
    // ... deleted, not needed...

    public:
        Vec3 operator+(const Vec3 &rh) const;
};

void test(Vec3 *a, Vec3 *b, Vec3 *c, size_t len)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

This seems to be an ordinary example for vectorization, but because operator+() is a user-defined function this loop will not auto-vectorize. I also tried adding `__declspec(vector)` as suggested [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-42986DEF-8710-453A-9DAC-2086EE55F1F5.htm), but this leads to an compilation error:

```
error: return type with class/struct/union is not supported in vector function
```

Maybe I've missunderstood what this prefix is doing. How can I make the function vectorizable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A traditional function can only be converted when the parameter to the function falls in one of the following catagories (This is a current limitation documented at https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-42986DEF-8710-453A-9DAC-2086EE55F1F5.htm under "Restrictions on using vector declaration"):

- (un)signed 8, 16, 32, or 64-bit integer
- 32 or 64-bit floating point
  64 or 128-bit complex
  a pointer (C++ reference is considered a
  pointer data type)

Your program is using a user defined data type Vec3 which doesn't fall in the above four catagories.